# Rust: E0597 when creating a vector of struct, borrowing/lifetime question

Tags: rust

I am fairly new to Rust and keep fighting the ownership mechanism.
I want to traverse a local directory and gather all the individual elements into a struct. The structs then go into a vector for later use. So basically I am trying to construct a vector of structs.
 
The first two fields of the struct should each contain a vector of the individual components of the path, the last two an OsString:

```
struct FileItem<'a> {
        g_base_dir: Vec<Component<'a>>, //base directory
        o_full_uri: Vec<Component<'a>>, //original full path
        o_filename: OsString,           //original filename
        o_extension: OsString,          //original extension
    }
```

I use "WalkDir" to traverse the directory and get a "DirEntry" for each individual item. My problem is that I am unable to push the constructed struct onto the vector:

```
fn main() {
    let mut file_item_collection: Vec<FileItem> = Vec::new();

    let base_dir = Path::new("D:\\test");

    for entry in WalkDir::new(base_dir).into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        let current_file = FileItem {
            g_base_dir: base_dir.components().collect::<Vec<_>>(),
            o_full_uri: entry.path().components().collect::<Vec<_>>(),
            o_filename: integrity_check(1, &entry).unwrap(),
            o_extension: integrity_check(2, &entry).unwrap(),
        };

        file_item_collection.push(current_file);
    }

    for item in &file_item_collection {
       println!("{:?}", item.o_full_uri);
    }
```

The assignment for `o_full_uri` fails because:

```
`entry` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enough rustc(E0597)
main.rs(56, 5): `entry` dropped here while still borrowed
main.rs(55, 9): borrow later used here
```

I get that `entry` falls out of scope, but I can't figure out what to do about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Taking the input from @Hadus and @kmdreko into account the solution looks like this and works fine:

```
struct FileItem {
    g_base_dir: Vec<OsString>, //global base directory
    o_full_uri: Vec<OsString>, //original full path
    o_filename: OsString,      //original filename
    o_extension: OsString,     //original extension
}
```

```
fn main() {
    let mut file_item_collection: Vec<FileItem> = Vec::new();

    let base_dir = Path::new("D:/test");

    let entries: Vec<DirEntry> = WalkDir::new(base_dir)
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
        .collect();

    for entry in &entries {
        if entry.path().is_file() {
            let current_file = FileItem {
                g_base_dir: base_dir
                    .components()
                    .map(|e| e.as_os_str().to_os_string())
                    .collect(),
                o_full_uri: entry
                    .path()
                    .components()
                    .map(|e| e.as_os_str().to_os_string())
                    .collect(),
                o_filename: entry.path().file_stem().unwrap_or_default().to_os_string(),
                o_extension: entry.path().extension().unwrap_or_default().to_os_string(),
            };
            file_item_collection.push(current_file);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: As you may have guessed from the lifetime parameter `'a`, a `Component` is just a reference to a portion of a `Path` of which goes out of scope. Judging by your usage, you may be looking for [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) instead of a vector of components?

Comment: @kmdreko Thank you for answering! Unfortunately, I really need an array like breakdown of the individual parts of the path. I am writing a program that organizes image files in a human readable way and regroups them in a dynamically generated (new) folder structure. Yet, I agree that component vector is not what I wanted/needed. I switched to a vector of OsString and it is a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the problem of the `entry` not living long enough. Consider this simplification:

```rust
let mut things = vec![];

{
    // things inside here live till the end of this scope
    let entry = 7;
        
    // this won't work because entry will be dropped when
    // the scope exits and we would be pointing to nothing
    things.push(&entry);
}

// here entry doesn't exist anymore
```

**The problem is that you are trying to store a reference pointing into an inner scope in an outer scope. You must only have references pointing into the same scope or a higher scope.**

For example this is fine (same scope):

```rust
let mut things = vec![];

// lives as long as things
let entry = 7;

{
    // this will work
    things.push(&entry);
}

// here entry and things still both exist
```

And this is fine too (higher scope):

```rust
// lives longer than things
let entry = 7;

{
    let mut things = vec![];

    // this will work
    things.push(&entry);
}
```

We have to make sure the `entry` doesn't get dropped at the end of the `while` loop (using same scope):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut file_item_collection: Vec<FileItem> = Vec::new();

    let base_dir = Path::new("D:\\test");

    // the entries are now stored outside the while loop
    // so they do live long enough
    let entries: Vec<DirEntry> = WalkDir::new(base_dir)
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
        .collect();

    for entry in &entries {
        ...
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Anyway are you sure you have to store these pesky `Component`s?

Comment: I do need the breakdown of the path, but I did away with some of the overkill. Your solution worked great. It just did not occur to me that I could pull out the 'entries' variable and thus re-scope. Thank you for taking the time and guiding me through your thought process. I will mark this answer and edit my post to reflect the changes.